# A linear algebra "game" with binary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and an arbitrary binary matrix $M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ of full rank be given such that the last row of $M$ equals $(1,1,\ldots,1)$. The following problem arose from a research question I have been working on recently.

The core mechanic of the "game" is about taking any two rows $m_j,m_k$ of $M$ and partitioning them into $\min\{m_j,m_k\},\max\{m_j,m_k\}$ where $\min,\max$ operate entrywise. Just as an example to make things clear, if $m_j=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0  \end{pmatrix}$ and $m_k=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ then
$$
\min\{m_j,m_k\}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\max\{m_j,m_k\}=\begin{pmatrix}  1&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and, obviously, $m_j+m_k=\min\{m_j,m_k\}+\max\{m_j,m_k\}$. 
Starting from $M_0:=M$ there are three possible scenarios:

1. Neither $\min\{m_j,m_k\}$ nor $\max\{m_j,m_k\}$ are a row of $M_0$. Then do nothing.
2. Either $\min\{m_j,m_k\}$ or $\max\{m_j,m_k\}$ are a row of $M_0$ (but not both). Then extend $M$ by the other row vector. (Here we use the convention that the $0$ vector is a row of $M$ so if $\min\{m_j,m_k\}=0$ then extend $M_0$ by $\max\{m_j,m_k\}$ to get a new matrix $M_1$.)
3. Both $\min\{m_j,m_k\}$ and $\max\{m_j,m_k\}$ are a row of $M_0$. Then do nothing.

Repeat this process (where $M_0$ becomes $M_l$ and $M_1$ becomes $M_{l+1}$ in step $l\in\mathbb N_0$) until for **every** two rows of $M_l$ scenario 2 does not occur anymore, i.e. it is maximal in this sense and no other row is added via this scheme (then denoted by $M_\text{max}$). Now the "game" ends with a **victory** if there exist rows $m_{i_1},\ldots,m_{i_n}$ of $M_\text{max}$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}m_{i_1}\\\vdots\\m_{i_n}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&&\ddots&0\\
1&\cdots&\cdots&1
\end{pmatrix}\underline{\sigma}\tag{1}
$$
for some permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ (where $\underline{\sigma}$ is the corresponding permutation matrix. This is equivalent to saying that $m_{i_{l+1}}$ arises from $m_{i_l}$ by turning a $0$ into a $1$ for all $l=1,\ldots,n-1$.

This concept should become a lot clearer again by considering an example.

> **Example 1.** Let
>   $$
> M=M_0=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&0&0&0\\
> 0&1&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&1\\
> 1&1&1&1
> \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m_1\\m_2\\m_3\\m_4\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}
> $$
>   which is of full rank so we may start the game using this matrix. Now take for example $m_2$ and $m_3$ so
>   $$
> \min\{m_2,m_3\}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\max\{m_2,m_3\}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\,.
> $$
>   Because $\max\{m_2,m_3\}$ is a row of $M$ but $\min\{m_2,m_3\}$ is not, apply Step 2 to get
>   $$
> M_1=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&1&0\\
> 0&1&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&1\\
> 1&1&1&1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   Doing the same for $m_1$ and (now) $m_3$ yields $\max\{m_1,m_3\}=(1\ 1\ 1\ 0)$ and $\min\{m_1,m_3\}=(0\ 0\ 0\ 0)$. By our convention this again is Scenario 2 so we extend $M_1$ by $(1\ 1\ 1\ 0)$ to get
>   $$M_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&1&0\\
> 0&1&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&1\\
> 1&1&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Once more for $m_4,m_5$ and we arrive at
>   $$
> M_3=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&1&0\\
> 0&1&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&1\\
> 1&1&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&1
> \end{pmatrix}=M_\text{max}\,.
> $$
>   One readily verifies that for any two rows of $M_3$ the above rule ends in Scenario 3 (so in particular not in Scenario 2, nothing new can be generated anymore) which shows maximality. 
>   The submatrices of $M_\text{max}$ which satisfy the winning condition read
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&0&0&0\\
> 1&0&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&1\\
> 1&1&1&1 
> \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&0&0&0\\
> 1&0&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&1
> \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0&0&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&1\\
> 1&1&1&1
> \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0&0&1&0\\
> 1&0&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&1
> \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0&0&1&0\\
> 0&1&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&0\\
> 1&1&1&1
> \end{pmatrix}\tag{3}
> $$

One can also reformulate the problem in terms of directed graphs, which may (or may not) be a good alternative approach here but it certainly visualizes this problem in a nice way. Turn row vectors $\{m_1,\ldots,m_l\}$ into vertices $\{v_1,\ldots,v_l\}$ and draw an arrow from $v_j$ to $v_k$ whenever $v_k-v_j$ is a standard basis vector (i.e. $v_k-v_j$ consists of $n-1$ zeros and one $1$). Again by convention, $(0\ \ldots\ 0)$ is turned into a vertex as well. The victory condition then is met if and only if there exists a path from $(0\ \ldots\ 0)$ to $(1\ \ldots\ 1)$ which is equivalent to $A_\text{max}^n\neq 0$ with $A_\text{max}$ the adjacency matrix of the graph corresponding to $M_\text{max}$.

> **Example 1 (directed graphs-version).** The graph of the original $M$ from (2) is
>   [image: 3]
>   with adjacency matrix
>   $$A_0=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\,.$$
>   Then $M_1$ converts to
>   [image: 2]
>   with adjacency matrix
>   $$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&\color{blue}1&0&0&0\\0&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&0\\\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0\\0&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&0\\0&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&1 \\0&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
>   followed by
>   [image: 1]
>   $$A_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&0&0&\color{blue}0&0\\
> 0&0&0&0&0&\color{blue}0&0\\
> 0&0&0&1&0&\color{blue}0&0\\
> 0&0&0&0&0&\color{blue}1&0\\
> 0&0&0&0&0&\color{blue}0&1\\
> \color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}1\\
> 0&0&0&0&0&\color{blue}0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
>   and
>   [image: 4]
>   $$
> A_3=A_\text{max}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0&0&\color{blue}1&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0&1&\color{blue}1&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0&0&\color{blue}0&0&1&0\\
> \color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}0\\
> 0&0&0&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&1\\
> 0&0&0&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&1\\
> 0&0&0&0&\color{blue}0&0&0&0  \end{pmatrix}\,.$$
>   The blue numbers are the ones that are added in the corresponding step.
>   Also note that the adjacency matrices of the individual steps are necessarily triangular.
>   Now the victory condition is met if and only if $A_\text{max}^4\neq 0$. Indeed $A_\text{max}^4=5 e_1e_n^T$ so there exist 5 different paths (corresponding to eq.(3)) that lead from $(0\ \ldots\ 0)$ to $(1\ \ldots\ 1)$. Be aware that $A_2^4=e_1e_n^T\neq 0$ becasue there is one path from $\vec 0$ to $\vec 1$ so we already won after the second step.

The whole time I put the word "game" in quotation marks for the following reason:

> **Conjecture 1.** For every $M$ satisfying the above conditions the game ends in a victory, i.e. $M_\text{max}$ contains at least one submatrix of form (1). Equivalently the directed graph corresponding to $M_\text{max}$ contains at least one path leading from from $(0\ \ldots\ 0)$ to $(1\ \ldots\ 1)$, i.e. $A_\text{max}^n\neq 0$.

A useful intermediate step *might* be the following:

> **Conjecture 2.** Let $M$ satisfying the above conditions be given. For any two rows $m_j,m_k$ of $M_\text{max}$ only scenario 3 can occur.

These conjectures are supported by a plethora of examples I have computed (up to $n=6$) which makes me rather confident that this is true. Two short comments to make here.

1. The full rank condition on $M$ cannot be waived or replaced by something like "all rows of $M$ have to be pairwise distinct". For this consider
   $$
   M=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}=M_\text{max}
   $$
   which does obviously not satisfy the winning condition (although for any two rows, Scenario 3 occurs).
2. Having one row equal to $(1\ \ldots\ 1)$ is necessary. Consider
   $$
   M=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}=M_\text{max}\,,
   $$
   cf. also mjacobse's answer.

I am currently lacking ideas on how to approach this problem. Working with the adjacency matrices seems like a possibility, although I neither see how the rank of $M$ is reflected in $A_\text{max}$ nor do I see a general pattern there yet. The only thing I see is that if $M_1,M_2\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ of full rank satisfy $M_1=M_2\underline{\tau}$ for some permutation $\tau\in S_n$ then $M_1$ leads to victory if and only if $M_2$ does---so we can reduce this problem to equivalence classes of initial matrices but this should at best be a simplification, not an idea for a proof. Thank you in advance for any comments and or ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a quick [python script](https://gist.github.com/mjacobse/f44b5c13a22f096a3869b794c264aee4) to try to bruteforce counter examples. Unfortunately, it quickly found the counter examples

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0& 1& 1\\ 1& 0& 1\\ 1& 1& 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

if the last row does not have to be only ones and among others

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& 1& 0\\ 1& 1& 0& 0\\ 0& 1& 1& 0\\ 1& 1& 1& 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

if it does.

Comment: Interesting, the second counterexample loses its effect if one extends the rules to allow sums of more than two rows (related to the inclusion-exclusion principle) because then $1010+1100+0110=2220=2*(1110)+(0000)$ and we get $1110$ as a new row etc. But that is beyond what my current question asks so this works and I learned something. Great job!

Comment: Just curious, in condition 1, if we instead add the two rows to $M$, do you find counterexamples?

Comment: @vujazzman Could not find any in a quick run for matrix dimensions smaller than 10. Would have to put some effort into a more efficient script to do more rigorous testing. However, I would not be surprised if there aren't any counter examples in that case. It feels like pretty much any possible binary row would be in the matrix at some point.